# I don't see the image I'm adding - UWP

Tags: c#, image, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to make a memory game, code shown below:

```
<Page
x:Class="MemoGame.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MemoGame"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" FontSize="24" FontStyle="Italic">Memo game by Ido and Jacob</TextBlock>

    <Rectangle x:Name="R1C1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R1C2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R1C3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R1C4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>

    <Rectangle x:Name="R2C1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R2C2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R2C3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R2C4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>

    <Rectangle x:Name="R3C1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R3C2" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R3C3" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R3C4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>

    <Rectangle x:Name="R4C1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R4C2" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R4C3" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle x:Name="R4C4" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="4" Stroke="Black"></Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

However, when I add an image, I can't see it. I set up the image as below:

```
        <Image Source="c:\users\prinsnal\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MemoGame\MemoGame\Assets\I3LeJ3H.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Image>
```

Nothing is showing, the picture exists and I dragged it from the assets, what should I do to be able to see the picture? Should I place a picture and a textblock or a button on the same panel?

Comment: Did you have a look at the examples in the [Image.Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source.aspx) page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Image Source="Assets\I3LeJ3H.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Image>
```

The image must added in Visual Studio in the Assets directory. If it isn't:

1. Right click on the Assets directory in Visual Studio
2. Add
3. Exists Element
4. Select your image

[image: It works for me]